# Dynamically Changing docker compose service image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have a docker-compose file with service like

```
services:
    utils-microservice:
        container_name: utils-microservice
        image: <Masked>.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/utils-microservice:<Some Tag>
        ports:
        - '1024:1024'
        env_file:
        - './envs/utils-microservice.env'
```

**Now, what we want to do?**

Once CI Pushes a new TAG to ECR, We can run a shell script to achieve the following

1 Stop the container
2 Replace the utils-microservice:<Some Tag> to utils-microservice:<Some New Tag>
3 Restart the service with new tag!

Is it achievable? we are not looking to complicate using docker swarm or k8's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s possible to use environment variables in your shell to populate values inside a Compose file:

web:
image: "webapp:${TAG}"

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/